# What is the difference between fireplace gas lighter and burner?

Tags: fireplace, gas-burner

Is it a gas lighter in my fireplace, or is it a burner? Do I need to buy gas burner with gas logs, or can I just place the gas logs on the grate to start using my fireplace?

[image]

Comment: I haven't seen a setup like that.  Typically you have a thermocouple, a pilot and then the burner.  How do you light your fireplace?

Comment: That looks more than a little home-made to me. I'm all for DIY, but something like that makes me very uncomfortable ...

Comment: I would remove that and cap the gas at source. We had a gas poker on a flexible pipe connected to a small gas cylinder which we brought out as needed. But setting the fire with starting materials works well especially when all is properly dry, trying to burn wet wood is never good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is a gas starter for lighting wood logs to start a fire in your fireplace.
I've seen them before in some older homes and it's simply a means of getting a fire started easily without using kindling. After the logs catch you turn the gas off. Some have thermocouples as a safety precaution so that gas can't be released without the presence of a flame. In the picture you provided a thermocouple isn't evident so you truly need to be careful to prevent the possibility of being overcome by gas or a possible explosion.
If you have young children you might want to turn off the gas line at it's source to prevent an accidental release of gas.
You also might want to bring in a qualified gas fireplace installer to check it out to be sure you have the proper safeguards.